# TypeError: this.state.posts.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios

I Get some problem when i am use react and laravel-api this my code

```js
import React from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'


class Post extends React.Component{
        state = {
          posts: []
        }

        componentDidMount() {
          axios.get(`http://192.168.0.42/blog/laravel/blog/public/api/posts/11`)
            .then(res => {
              const posts = res.data;
              this.setState({ posts });
            })
        }

        render() {
          return (
            <ul>
              { this.state.posts.map(posts => <li>{posts.id}</li>)}
            </ul>
          )
        }

}

export default Post
```

I Get Error 
Image : http://prntscr.com/oug5v3

Text

> > TypeError: this.state.posts.map is not a function

someone Help

Comment: Please use the in-browser JS debugger to find what the actual value of `posts` is when this exception occurs. Otherwise you could simply try to `console.log` it.

Comment: I guess, `res.data` is Object instead Array. And you are doing Get the request of .../posts/11

Comment: @SajibKhan that's my guess too. That's why we should see what that variable actually is first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess without actually seeing the contents of the `posts` state member is that you actually retrieve an object from that HTTP request, instead of an array.

So what happens is the first render works well, because an empty array is still an array (thus having the `map` method), and then, when the request finishes, you replace the `posts` state variable with an object (not having the `map` method).

As I pointed out in a comment to your question, you should inspect the actual value of what comes out from that HTTP request.

If you're using the in-browser debugger, you should place a breakpoint on this line:

```
this.setState({ posts });
```

then check the value of `posts`.

If you don't want to use a debugger (however I don't recommend that), you can simply place a `console.log(posts)` before the line mentioned above.

### Tip

If you're developing a REST API, then the `http://192.168.0.42/blog/laravel/blog/public/api/posts/11` URL should actually return **one post**, not a list.

My guess is that you should actually make the request to `http://192.168.0.42/blog/laravel/blog/public/api/posts` (notice the `/11` part gone).